# Python list referencing same dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pointers

I encountered behavior in Python that I didn't expect when appending a dictionary to a list. Specifically, I tried

```
list_val=[]
local_dict={}
for val in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    local_dict['first']=val
    list_val.append(local_dict)
    print(list_val)
```

which produces

```
[{'first': 'a'}]
[{'first': 'b'}, {'first': 'b'}]
[{'first': 'c'}, {'first': 'c'}, {'first': 'c'}]
```

Using the page [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) I'm able to watch the steps execute and I see that each list element points to the same dictionary that is being altered.

The fix is to declare the dictionary inside the loop,

```
list_val=[]
for val in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    local_dict={}
    local_dict['first']=val
    list_val.append(local_dict)
    print(list_val)
```

which produces

```
[{'first': 'a'}]
[{'first': 'a'}, {'first': 'b'}]
[{'first': 'a'}, {'first': 'b'}, {'first': 'c'}]
```

The reason the behavior is unexpected is because I'm used to appending values to list like this:

```
list_val=[]
for val in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    list_val.append(val)
    print(list_val)
```

which produces

```
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Where should I expect to see pointer-like behavior?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) but my observation isn't related to functions.

Comment: Another relevant (but not quite duplicate) question: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/364696)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: The [lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) is similar but less unexpected since the "* 3" operation is easy to understand as "make three copies of this variable". In my question the loop plays a similar role but I was more surprised that the list is pointing to the same variable.

Comment: The two examples you've show work **exactly the same**. Everything in Python acts like a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer-like behavior is actually happening all the time. It's just that immutable types are safe; they always get replaced, even when you use operations (like `+=`) that *logically* mutate in place, but are not implemented that way for immutable objects.

You'll see this problem any time you repeatedly append the same object. In:

```
list_val=[]
local_dict={}
for val in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    local_dict['first']=val
    list_val.append(local_dict)
    print(list_val)
```

you never rebind `local_dict` to a new object, so it's always the same `dict`, and you keep appending that same `dict` over and over. By contrast, in:

```
list_val=[]
for val in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    local_dict={}
    local_dict['first']=val
    list_val.append(local_dict)
    print(list_val)
```

the line `local_dict={}` is rebinding the name `local_dict` to a completely new `dict`, unrelated to the one it used to be bound to.

As I mentioned, immutable types will behave "safely", so you can't just look at a portion of the code and know if it's safe without knowing the types involved. For example:

```
list_val = []
for val in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    x += val
    list_val.append(x)
    print(list_val)
```

is entirely safe (inserting three unrelated `str`) if `x` is a `str` (immutable), but will insert three references to the same `list` if `x` is a `list` (mutable). If you're not sure, and need to make sure independent versions are inserted no matter what, you can copy (deep for safety, shallow for performance if you know only shallow copies are needed) at the moment of insertion, by importing the `copy` module, and replacing:

```
    list_val.append(x)
```

with:

```
    list_val.append(copy.deepcopy(x))
```

As it happens, for immutable types, `copy.deepcopy` is typically inexpensive (it pretends to copy, but doesn't actually do so, since it doesn't need to), so in cases where safety is paramount, it's a way of removing all doubt, without significantly reducing the performance when the types involved were already safe.

Comment: I think in your first paragraph your last line is meant to read "not implemented that way for immutable objects" ?

Comment: @Ben: I'm not sure what you're getting at. That's exactly the wording I used...

Answer (score 0):

You already noticed that each `list_val.append` call points to the same dictionary so when you update the dictionary, each item in your list gets updated. This is expected behaviour in python. This is because variables in python are all pointers to addresses (rather than references). 
This behavior is also manifest in other ways:

```
A =[1,2,3]
B=A
B.append(4)
print(A)
# prints [1,2,3,4] as opposed to [1,2,3]
```

This is because when I say `B=A`, they both point to the same address thereon { verify this: `id(B)==id(A)`}; so they'll always be same.
Similarly in your case think that your list is made of pointers to whatever your local_dict defines (rather than the values), hence the behaviour.
You can check out `copy` library for a workaround.